# Tosca and Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, continuous-integration, tosca

Does anybody work with Tosca and Jenkins?

I have problems to run my batch script from Jenkins. It does not open browser, but job is finished successfully. Batch script runs normally when I try to run in on Windows, without Jenkins.

Anybody has an experience using these two tools together?

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried that. But in any case, Jenkins does not open the browser, so Tests from Execution List  and I do not know why.

We use Tosca 10.

Comment: This "answer" should have been posted as a comment to the answer written by MartinThe

Answer (score 2):

In order to use Tosca CI with Jenkins you need to:

1. Configure your Jenkins build project
2. Add an additional build step (Execute Windows batch command)
3. Call ToscaCIClient.exe/ToscaCIClient.jar with parameters
   e.g. "PathToTosca\ToscaCI\Client\ToscaCIClient.exe" -t junit -r PathToResults\result.xml

Further information can be found here: https://support.tricentis.com/community/article.do?number=KB0012411

Answer (score 0):

The issue your facing is because your running Jenkins as windows service, in this case headless execution happens technically your script is executed for other user account.

Solution
Instead of installing Jenkins host it on Apache Tomcat server

1. Download Jenkins war file
2. Copy it inside webapps folder of Tomcat
3. Run startup.bat

Refer-
 https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_tomcat_setup.htm

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue.

I am guessing your slave machine running the test has jenkins services installed as services.
Uninstall the service. (.jenkins/jenkins-slave.exe uninstall)
Use the .jnlp or slave.jar to connect the machine as a slave.
Your test should run fine after that.

If it does just create a batch file to connect the machine as slave whenever it is logged in.